# VIM: Characters not displayed correctly in GVIM 7.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vim, ubuntu-10.04, gvim

Using GVIM 7.4.52 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in a Virtualbox VM. Sometimes the characters are not displayed correctly as can be seen in the following image

[image]

This totally renders GVIM unusable. The problem occurs in new files but also during editing of existing files. In VIM itself the problem is not reproducable. However, with `gvim -u None -N` the problem is allready visible:

[image]

These (unsolved) questions might be related to this issue:

- [gvim (version 7.4.52 and 7.4.622) doesn't refresh properly on Ubuntu (14.04 LTS)](https://superuser.com/questions/875664/gvim-version-7-4-52-and-7-4-622-doesnt-refresh-properly-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)
- [gvim redraw failure](https://superuser.com/questions/343599/gvim-redraw-failure?rq=1)

The screenshot above shows GVIM with some plugins and my personal vimrc loaded. But the problem also exists on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 with the default VIM configuration.

Comment: Is this using default settings, or have you changed anything?

Comment: The screenshot above uses some VIM Plugins and other configuration, but the problem also persist on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 and VIM.

Comment: can you reproduce using `gvim -u NONE -N` I think this is a font problem.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, I've added a screenshot of `gvim -u NONE -N`, as you can see the problem still exists.

Comment: can you try a different font?

Comment: This could also be [issue 91](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/91)